# RavenDb Stream returning no results

Tags: ravendb

I am an absolute beginner to RavenDb, but very experienced in EF and repository pattern using SQL. Finally getting around to trying it out, so I created a simple console application using RavenDB.Embedded with the intention of replacing an aging SQLLite EF implementation on another application.

Anyhow I am attempting to write 1000+ records to the store, and simply read it out with a stream. The following is some sample code:

```
var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
        {
            DataDirectory = "data"
        };
        store.Initialize();



        using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
        {

            for (var t = 1; t < 1000; t++)
            {
                var subtest = new Test
                {
                    Id = new Guid(),
                    SubTest = new SubTest
                    {
                        Name = "NewTest",
                        Id = new Guid()
                    }
                };                    
                session.Store(subtest);
            }
            session.SaveChanges();
        }

        store
            .DatabaseCommands
            .PutIndex("SubTest/All",
                new IndexDefinitionBuilder<SubTest>()
                {
                    Map = tests => tests
                        .Select(test => new
                        {
                            SubTest = test.SubTest,
                            Id = test.Id
                        })
                });

        using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            var query = session.Query<Test>("SubTest/All");

            var listt = query.ToList();

            using (var enumerator = session.Advanced.Stream(query))
            {
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var t = enumerator.Current.Document;
                    System.Console.WriteLine(t.Id);
                }
            };
        }

        System.Console.ReadLine();
```

I realize this is pretty rudimentary, and I not so much looking for somebody to correct my code. Just hoping somebody can help me understand how the index thing is supposed to work with a stream and maybe explain why the enumerator has no results. If I use .Load in stead of .Query I get results (128 of them) so I'm pretty sure the rest of it is working.

I tried the PutIndex thing above but I also tried AbstractIndexCreationTask with similarly confusing results. I cant really find a whole lot of info about this online strangely enough,  is this really that uncommon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured this out. Seems the documentation is lacking a few key details in regards to the Streaming API. Basically I was on the right track, I just had to actually create the index earlier in the code. I ended up using the AbstractIndexCreationTask, which I like better than the PutIndex method, although Im not sure if they are doing the same thing or not. In any case, this works:

```
        var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
        {
            DataDirectory = "data"
        };
        store.Initialize();

        **IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(TestIndex).Assembly, store);**

        using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
        {

            for (var t = 1; t < 100; t++)
            {
                var subtest = new Test
                {
                    Id = new Guid(),
                    SubTest = new SubTest
                    {
                        Name = "NewTest",
                        Id = new Guid()
                    }
                };
                session.Store(subtest);
            }
            session.SaveChanges();
        }


        using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            IQueryable<Test> query = session.Query<Test, TestIndex>();

            var enumerator = session.Advanced.Stream(query);

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var t = enumerator.Current.Document;
                System.Console.WriteLine(t.Id);
            }

        }
```

And My Index:

```
public class TestIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Test>
{
    public TestIndex()
    {
        this.Map = tests =>
            from t in tests
            select new
            {
                t.Id,
                t.SubTest
            };
    }
}
```

Comment: One interesting thing to note about this sample, is that the first time its run, the stream returns no results. Based on what I have read, this is because the data I just added has not been indexed yet, and stream does NOT wait for indexing.

Comment: PutIndex and creating an AbstractIndexCreationTask do the same thing: create an index. I recommend the latter.

Comment: The original example returns no items because they are not indexed yet. If you wait for the index to be non-stale (i.e finish indexing), then you would get results. (basically you've run into eventual consistency of RavenDB indexes).

Comment: Also, LoadDocument bypasses indexes, thus it retrieves documents regardless of indexing status

Comment: You are exactly right. I am so used to SQL this is a bit of a twist on what Im used to. But I like it! I like the simplicity of it. It eliminates a lot of code that I usually write on top of EF to make it easier to consume.